# Making Elixir write a program for itself

Tags: elixir

I am fairly new to programming and Elixir in general but I have a task in elixir and it goes as follows:
"Can you make Elixir write a program for itself? Put this code into a file called  `script.ex`  with
`File.write/2` :  `IO.puts "This file was generated from Elixir"` and then make it run by running
`elixir that-file.ex` ."

I have tried numerous ways to tackle this but to no avail, could anyone help me by showing me the proper way to implement this with an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

After some research and guidance I had come with a solution.

```elixir
# script.exs

defmodule ScriptWriter do
  # define module attribute @location which we can use as a constant
  @location "./generated.exs"

  def write_script do
    # write the script to @location
    # Note: you must "escape" the interior quotation marks with a forward-slash
    File.write!(@location, "IO.puts \"This file was generated from Elixir\"")
  end

  def run_script do
    # read the the string generated by write_script and evaluate it
    script = File.read!(@location)
    Code.eval_string(script)
  end
end

# these commands get executed when script.exs is run
ScriptWriter.write_script()
ScriptWriter.run_script()
```

Comment: Instead of calling `ScriptWriter.run_script()` when you run `script.exs`, I think the instructions wanted you to run `elixir generated.exs` to run the code in the generated file.

FYI: usually when people talk about Elixir code that "writes code", they are usually referring to Elixir macros, which is a fascinating and complex aspect of the language.

Comment: I was thinking that as well but seeing as this was a task in a beginner's book I would imagine it should be something that can be applied using minimal knowledge.
Also, calling `ScriptWriter.run_script()` actually does run it in a way seeing as it reads the code from the `@location` constant and assigns the contents to the `script` variable which is later evaluated using `Code.eval_string`